# UWP app can no longer create app packages

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP app that I've been working on for months. The app builds and runs fine from Visual Studio.

I have created app packages for sideloading many times in the past without any problem.

Today, when I tried to do this, I saw hundreds of error messages that make no sense. Most of them are like this: "error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported".

There are also a bunch that say "No way to resolve conflict between..." and "error CS0433: The type 'AssemblyTitleAttribute' exists in both 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'" or similar.

I have no idea what happened. All I did was come to work today and work on my application. I changed nothing with regard to the project properties. I did not install any Windows or VS updates.

What does all of this mean? What went wrong? How do I fix it?

How did a project that worked fine yesterday end up in this state?

Comment: Please try to modify your target version and min version to another.

Comment: Modify it to what? A higher number or lower? How do I know what versions exist and what they do?

Comment: Please try to modify version lower

Answer (score 0):

I get this type of error frequently when creating UWP app packages.  I usually do the following to solve the problem:

1. Make sure NuGet Packages are updated or in sync among apps and
   libraries (if any).
2. If the errors remain, restart Visual Studio.
3. If the errors still remain, delete C:\Users\myuserid.nuget\packages

The vast majority of my UWP app problems are related to .Net Native used to create app packages.